# Very simple ajax is not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am new to ajax.
I have three files sentenceArrange.php, script.js, query.php all in the same directory.

In sentenceArrange.php, I wrote:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
         </script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <input type="button" value="Check" onClick="test();">
    </body>
</html>
```

In script.js, I wrote:

```
function test(){
    alert("Hello");//Runs Successfully.
    $.ajax({
        url:"query.php",
        success:function(msg){
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

In query.php, I wrote:

```
<?php
     echo "Hi from query.php";
?>
```

On button's click event, function test is called successfully but ajax is not working. I have made a silly mistake.
Help me.

Comment: Have you checked the console and network tabs of your browsers developer tools for errors and to see the AJAX?

Comment: Start with including `jQuery`

Comment: It looks as if you might have forgotten to include the jQuery library, hence, the `$.ajax` call did not work.

Comment: @u_mulder is right and [uuit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: + 1 for the aforementioned comments, unless he has jQuery inside `<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if you might have forgotten to include the jQuery library, hence, the `$.ajax` call did not work.

Include this in your head, before your script.js include:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js">
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the developer console (F12 on web browser)? Does it throw any errors? Check the network Tab to see the response of the Ajax call

Answer (score 0):

It is better to avoid adding event handlers in markup. A simple change will make this work.

Add an id to the button and remove the onclick handler from markup.

```
<input type="button" id="checkbtn" value="Check" >
```

Add an event handler using jquery.

```
function test(){
    alert("Hello");//Runs Successfully.
    $.ajax({
        url:"query.php",
        success:function(msg){
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
}

$('#checkbtn').on('click', function() {
    test();
});
```

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ug9d7u2L/)